# Django categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories

Tags: django

I have a simple category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank = True, null = True, related_name="children")
```

At first, my data seemed to need only categories and subcategories, but I realized that there are some cases where I still want to sub-sub-categorize.

I want my urls to be category/subcategory/sub-subcategory

I was thinking about how to implement this but I am not sure, since my url pattern matching looks like this:

```
url(r'^business/(?P<parent>[-\w]+)/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)$', 'directory.views.show_category'),
```

Basically only allowing a single sub-category, since my view method accepts these two parameters.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about unlimited levels? At urls.py:

```
url(r'^business/(?P<hierarchy>.+)/', 'directory.views.show_category')
```

And at directory/views.py:

```
def show_category(request, hierarchy):
    category_slugs = hierarchy.split('/')
    categories = []
    for slug in category_slugs:
        if not categories:
            parent = None
        else:
            parent = categories[-1]
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, parent=parent)
        categories.append(category)
    ...
```

Don't forget to add `unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)` to Category.Meta, otherwise you are doomed.

[update]

> could I just query the db with category_slugs[-1] and if the obtained category has no children, we know its a leaf category, otherwise, we know it has subcategories and we show them? – alexBrand

@alexBrand: consider the following hypothetical URLs:

```
/business/manufacture/frozen/pizza/
/business/restaurant/italian/pizza/
/business/delivery-only/italian/pizza/
/business/sports/eating-contest/pizza/
```

If you think such scenario is possible, then IMHO a simpler test (without the whole hierarchy) is not enough.

What are your real concerns regarding the proposed solution? At the end of the loop, the variable category will hold the correct `category_slugs[-1]`, and you will have the whole hierarchy available in `categories`. Don't worry about performance, my best advice is: don't try to optimize an elegant solution before profiling (you will be surprised).

Comment: could I just query the db with category_slugs[-1] and if the obtained category has no children, we know its a leaf category, otherwise, we know it has subcategories and we show them?

Comment: You are totally right. I did not think about the possibility of having the same sub-category names in different categories.

Comment: Where is the categories list being updated in the proposed solution though?

Comment: @PauloScardine, thanks for your answer! I'd have to with Alex though, where is `categories = []` getting updated? Thanks!

Comment: @MickyHulse: just append each category found in the loop to the categories array. I've updated the answer with such statement (but never really tested it, let me know if it works).

Comment: @PauloScardine Thank you!!!! I actually setup a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mhulse/django-purr) with a working example. Check out the `scripts/purr_tests.py` for a version of your code... I think the only modification I made was: `category_slugs = hierarchy.strip('/').split('/')`; for me, `hierarchy.split('/')` was returning: `['', 'business', 'sports', 'eating-contest', 'pizza', '']` and trimming the leading/trailing slashes made the code happy. Anyway, I'd love constructive feedback from you (or others). Thanks again!!! I really appreciate you sharing a cool solution! :)